# group names based on gender and count the number of them

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, data-analysis

A dataframe  looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a", "a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a"],
           'gender': ["male", "female", "female", "female", "male","male","male","female","female", "female", "male","male","male", "male"],
          'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019],
          'month':[1, 12, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 4, 3, 6 ],
          'count':[100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90]})
```

it shows the name, gender, birth year and the birth month, and the number of people. For example, in 2005 January there were 100 babies named “a”. I want to find top-10 frequent names for males and females. just as below:

[image]

this is my code :

```
f_data=data.groupby(['gender','name'])['count'].count().nlargest(10)
```

but how can I change the table to the wanted format
also, names can not be assumed to be duplicated. we need to sum them up for example we have 100 'a' in 2005 and 100 'a' in 2009 and so on. so in total we need to add them up like 100+ 100 and.the final result must be like a is male and totally in 10 years 500 people were named a and so on.

Answer (score 1):

## Edit Ver 2 : Remove duplicates

The below result does not have duplicates. Unfortunately, the values `'name'` had leading or trailing spaces. That took me a while to figure out. I am using unique() and [:10] slice to get the top 10.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "a", "a"],
           'gender': ["male", "female", "female", "female", "male","male","male","female","female", "female", "male","male","male", "male"],
          'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019],
          'month':[1, 12, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 4, 3, 6 ],
          'count':[100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90]})

df.sort_values(['gender','count'],ascending=False,inplace=True)
print (df)
male = df.loc[df['gender']=='male']['name'].unique()[:10]
print (male)
female = df[df['gender']=='female']['name'].unique()[:10]
results = pd.DataFrame({'Male':pd.Series(male),'Female':pd.Series(female)})
print (results)
```

The output of this will be:

```
  Male Female
0    a      d
1    d      b
2    e      c
3  NaN      a
```

## Edit Ver 1

You don't need to groupby. Instead you need to sort the values in descending order and take the top 10 using head(10)

Here's how to get it done. Note that we don't have 10 male names and 10 female names. So I am using pd.Series to create the dataframe. This will also address mismatch between two lists (males have 8 items, females have 6 items).

The code is as shown below:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':["a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a", "a"," b", "c","d", "e","a"," a"],
           'gender': ["male", "female", "female", "female", "male","male","male","female","female", "female", "male","male","male", "male"],
          'year':[2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2019],
          'month':[1, 12, 4, 3, 6, 7, 2, 4, 5, 1, 12, 4, 3, 6 ],
          'count':[100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90, 34, 100, 30, 10, 90]})

df.sort_values(['gender','count'],ascending=False,inplace=True)
male = df[df['gender']=='male']['name'].head(10).to_list()
female = df[df['gender']=='female']['name'].head(10).to_list()
results = pd.DataFrame({'Male':pd.Series(male),'Female':pd.Series(female)})
print (results)
```

The output is:

```
  Male Female
0    a      d
1    a      b
2    d      c
3    a      b
4    e      c
5    a      a
6    e    NaN
7    a    NaN
```

Comment: I don't want the names to be repeated.the output should be like a d e for male for example

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. but they can not be assumed to be duplicated. we need to sum them up for example we have 100 'a' in 2005 and 100 'a' in 2009 and so on. so in total we need to add them up like 100+ 100 and.. but when you consider them duplicated we just have 100 'a' and the result is not right

Comment: so you want to sum and then find the top 10 ? can you please add these in the question section so i can review and update my answer tomorrow morning. its too late now

Comment: yes exactly. I changed the question. Thank you